# Update table from JOIN Shows #1064

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to execute this

```
  UPDATE product
SET Product_entr_notes = t2.note
    ,Product_entr_email = t2.email
    ,Product_entr_mobile = t2.Mobile
    ,Product_entr_phone = t2.Home_Phone
FROM product AS t1
INNER JOIN result AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.ACTID
```

But I am getting

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM product t1 INNER JOIN result t2 ON t1.id = t2.ACTID WHERE
>   t1.id = t2.ACTID' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `JOIN` right after `Update`, like:

```
UPDATE product t1
INNER JOIN result AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.ACTID
SET Product_entr_notes = t2.note
    ,Product_entr_email = t2.email
    ,Product_entr_mobile = t2.Mobile
    ,Product_entr_phone = t2.Home_Phone
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I saw this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server Which I tried. Thanks for the help.